# Inequality solution verification(positive solution)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following system of equation where all the free variables live in the integers that is are allowed to be integers only.

$x = l$

$y = 5n - 2l + 25$

$z = 10 - 2n$

For $l,n \in \mathbb{N}$

I need to compute how many positive solutions are there so I computed the following inequalities:

$x > 0 \rightarrow l > 0$

$y > 0 \rightarrow n > -5 + 2l/5$

$z > 0 \rightarrow n < -5$

To get how many solution we keep a fixed l and see how many $n$ we get and do that for each $n$ until we get values that pop us out of the inequality for example for $l = 1$ we have $n > -4.6$ hence we have $-4 \le n < 5$ so in this case their is $10$ solutions and we proceed like this I just want to verify my answer I got $105$ possible positive solutions is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mathematically** Your equations are equivalent to :
$$5(n+5)>2l>0\\ 5>n $$ 
so for fixed $l$ we have $\frac{2l}{5}<n+5<10$ this means that $0<l\leq24$ and the number of solution possible value of $n$ with $l$ fixed is exactly is $9-\lfloor \frac{2l}{5} \rfloor$ and so the number of solution is :
$$\sum_{l=1}^{24}(9-\lfloor \frac{2l}{5} \rfloor)=216-\sum_{l=1}^{24}\lfloor \frac{2l}{5} \rfloor $$

using [walframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5BFloor%5B2l%2F5%5D%2C%20%7Bl%2C%201%2C%2024%7D%5D%20) : we compute the sum, and we get the total number $216-110=106$

**Using Mathemateca**

```
sols = Solve[{x < 5, 5*(x + 5) > 2*y, y > 0}, {x, y}, Integers];
Length@sols
```

As output we find $106$

Comment: I changed my answer so I hope you see it ,the first answer is not correct!

Comment: yes I am reading it atm because I had 115 possible answer corresponding to the following intervals:
l = 1, -4 <= n < 5
l = 2, -4 <= n < 5
l = 3, -3 <= n < 5
l = 4, -3 <= n < 5
l = 5, -3 < n  < 5
l = 6, -2 <= n < 5
l = 7, -2 <= n < 5
l = 8, -1 <= n < 5
etc calculating all of them I get 115

Comment: In the first time I allowed $n=5$ which gives another $24$ solutions, but i corrected it, and I'm sure that the $106$ is the correct answer.

Comment: 1 moment I am checking your solution atm because I don't see anything wrong that I did in my calculations I had n > -5 + 2l / 5 and I just simply varried l until n >= 5.

Comment: alright I am checking it at the moment.

Comment: however I noticed 1 thing though for l = 23 n > -5 + 2*23 /5 = 4.2 which is not possible my last value that I stopped at was 22 since for l = 22 we get n > 3.8 hence n = 4.

Comment: First notice that when $l=1$ there is only $9$ solutions and not $10$, when $l=23$ In my answer $\lfloor \frac{2*23}{5} \rfloor=9$ so my answer still correct because it says that there is $9- \lfloor \frac{2*23}{5} \rfloor=0$ solutions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21964/discussion-between-elaqqad-and-illustionist).

Comment: Good thanks alot I got 106 solutions.